# How to uppercase every letter of my input sentences? (In Java)

Tags: java, arrays, string

First I want to give number of the sentences the user wanted to leave and when his writing ends my codes start to capitalize first letters of every word (in Java).

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class India {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = input.nextInt();
        num = num + 1;
        String[] array = new String[num];
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) 
        {
            array[i] = input.nextLine();
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) 
        {
            StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
            for (String s1 : array[j].split(" ")) 
            {
                char[] str = s1.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
                if (str.length > 0) 
                {
                    str[0] = Character.toUpperCase(str[0]);
                    a.append(str);
                    a.append(' ');
                }
                System.out.println(a);
            }
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

And the new problem is
[image]

Comment: The `Exception` shown in the **link to an image** is most likely caused by `<= num + 1` of the first `for` loop. You are initializing the array with `num` as length, which means there won't be an item with index `num` or `num + 1`.

Comment: @deHaar well i fix that after you told me but I face with another problem! now I when I enter 3 for 3 sentences it will get 2 sentences and again error! Example : `HeLLo JAVA >>>> Exception in thread "main" Hello 
Hello Java 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at India.main(India.java:18)

Comment: Again `j <= i++` is a problem. You could do reinitialize the variable  `i` as `i=num` after the first `for loop` and then change `j<=i++` to `j<i`. Or simply avoid using `i` and change the condition to `j<num`.

Comment: Your code has a lot of problems... You have an uninitialized `int i` **and** an `int i = 0` as counter variable in the first `for` loop. Then in the second `for` loop you are referring to one of these while incrementing it in the conditional part of the loop in addition to the regular increment of that loop. It appears that you want to nest those two loops, but the second one is executed after the first one was left... Fix those things, too.

Comment: @MathewsMathai Thanks it works. but still need to work on it. check my code again I made some edit for that.

Comment: @deHaar I edit my code again and I face with new problem

Comment: I would omit the superfluous caching of the inputs in `String[] array`. That would make Your program more simple.

Comment: @Kaplan well I'm not allow to use that

Comment: @Kaplan input is needed. I just getting crazy of it that why my code take part my sentence and print it

Comment: In addition to the errors mentioned above, after `input.nextInt ()` an `input.nextLine ()` must follow. You should understand my short solution first eg. by debugging, than You will find Your errors more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your program a little simple by using apache StringUtils class. Inner loop in your program can be replaced by one liner. See if ut helps

Examples

```
StringUtils.capitalize(null)  = null
StringUtils.capitalize("")    = ""
StringUtils.capitalize("cat") = "Cat"
StringUtils.capitalize("cAt") = "CAt"
StringUtils.capitalize("'cat'") = "'cat'"
```

Answer (score 0):

*if the input is not needed after printing, the program can be shortened considerably*

```
Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
int num = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
for( int j = 0; j < num; j++ ) {
  Arrays.asList( input.nextLine().split( "(?<= )" ) ).forEach( s -> {
    System.out.print( StringUtils.capitalize( s ) );
  } );
  System.out.println();
}
input.close();
```

the changes to the original program:
– the `String[] array` is omitted
– the inner for-loop is replaced by the `forEach` lambda
– the argument for `split` is now `"(?<= )"` which keeps the blanks at the end of each separated string

after the `input.nextInt()` a pending `\n` must be read by a following `input.nextLine()`